# Use libxlsxwriter without CocoaPods in a macOS project

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods, libxlsxwriter

My project (Objective C, macOS, Xcode 11) does not use CocoaPods and I'd like to keep it that way.

I want to use libxlsxwriter to export data in Excel format. I cloned [libxlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter) from GitHub and built it. Now I have `libxlsxwriter.a` and `lbixlsxwriter.dylib`.

What I tried so far: I followed the instructions on [this site](http://www.vislab.net/people/john-stavrakakis/johns-blog/xcodehowtolinkdyliblibraryfiles) (thanks for the link) to include the dylib. In the "General" settings `lbixlsxwriter.dylib` is shown as "Embed & Sign", in "Build Phases" it is listed under "Link Binary With Libraries" and it has its own "Copy Files" section. Running from Xcode gives me

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libxlsxwriter.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXefxsacdsioejobcumpvsbklqguri/Build/Products/Debug/XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/XXX
  Reason: image not found
```

What do I have to add to my project: The include folder with all the header files and both of these libs? How do I have to adjust the General settings and Build Phases?

Comment: Have you tried steps such as http://www.vislab.net/people/john-stavrakakis/johns-blog/xcodehowtolinkdyliblibraryfiles ?

Comment: @alexyorke Not before you mentioned it. But it still gives me an "image not found" error. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have static library and only one loader, eg. main executable, (so you don't need to share it between your components), then you don't need dynamic library at all.

Just add your `libxlsxwriter.a` into `Target > General > Frameworks and Libraries` section, and it will be linked in into your executable and just work.

If you really need shared dynamic library then you need to use `rpath` + `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` combination. (*Let me know if you need more details on this*).